# Saving DataTable Back To DataBase with LINQ

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I Have database. I get my data from database with LINQ and save in DATATABLES.
After I updated my DataTables.And now i want to save my datatables back to my database.But i want to use .How can I apply LINQ to DataTable  save it back to database?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq isn't always the right tool for the job... in that case, you should use a [`DbDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use DataTables on top of Linq2Sql, it already gives you strongly typed objects. You make the updates you want against your Linq2Sql model, then call `SubmitChanges()` on your Linq2Sql context.